# Axios HTTP requests not sending to Fastify backend

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, axios, fastify

I'm trying to send a simple get request to my fastify server with axios, but i keep getting this error in the terminal:

```
Network Error
at node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
at node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:114:22 in handleError
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:600:10 in setReadyState
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
```

The request works perfectly fine in postman though, so I thought it was cors related and installed fastify-cors but I'm still getting the same error.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: What is your cors setting and the axios code?

Comment: `fastify.register(require("fastify-cors"));` i also passed options in it before but nothing changed. The weird thing is when i run the app in the web browser, the data fetches from my local server just fine and displays in the data, but when I run the app in the android emulator or on my iphone via ExpoGo, the data doesn't display

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly fetch from your ip address, not your localhost. I fixed this by doing `axios.get('http://<myIPaddr>:<port>')`,

I was also told on the Fastify github help page to explicitly have the Fastify server listen on host '0.0.0.0'

`fastify.listen({ port: 5000, host: "0.0.0.0" })`

Now everything works fine.